# Prevent linux user from changing their password in ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, pam, passwd

How can I prevent users from changing their passwords? I still want to be able to change the passwords as root if necessary but keep the user from changing their password.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login) may be useful

Comment: Chmod the passwd command so that only you can execute it

Comment: Why would you want to lower user security?

Comment: @mdpc I don't. I plan on changing the password periodically, but I need it to be changed by me because it is a shared account and I don't want someone to change the password without the other people who have access being notified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do `chmod go-rx /usr/bin/passwd` Normal users can then not run passwd. If you want some users to be able to, you can put them in a special group perhaps.

Comment: Would this still work? `cp /usr/bin/passwd . ; chmod +x ./passwd ; ./passwd`

Comment: @f.ardelian The thing is, `passwd` has some special magic called "setuid" on it - that means that when someone runs the file, they're running it as its owner (namely, root.) This allows normal users to change the `/etc/shadow` file containing the passwords. If you were to copy the file to a user's home directory, it would no longer be setuid, and therefore no longer be automatically run with root priviledges. To learn more, look up information about "Unix permissions" and "setuid".

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Thanks, that was very informative!

Answer (score 4):

`passwd -n 9999 user` will prevent `user` from changing his password for almost 274 years.

If you want to have passwordless `user`, which is unable to change his password, open `/etc/shadow` as root, find the line which begins with the name of the user, and change the content between first and second colon to `U6aMy0wojraho`.
<sup>(source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PasswordlessGuestAccount)</sup>